# Default constructor not being called c++ OOP

Tags: c++, oop, g++, default-constructor

So I'm making a program in c++ to handle vectors, and it's mostly there, but I just wanted to test it, so I have this:

```
class vector3 {
    protected: 
        double x,y,z;  

    public: 
        // Default 3 vector Constructor
        vector3() { 
            cout << "Default constructor called." << endl;
            x=y=z=0; 
        }
    vector3(double xin, double yin, double zin) {
        cout << "parametrised constructor called." << endl;
        x=xin;
        y=yin;
        z=zin;
    }
};
```

(there's more stuff, things for `<<` etc)

and as `main()` I have:

```
int main() {

    vector3 vec1();
    cout << "Vector 1: " << vec1 << endl;

    vector3 vec2(0, 0, 0);
    cout << "Vector 2: " << vec2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives the output:

```
Vector 1: 1
Parametrised constructor called.
Vector 2: (0,0,0)
Destroying 3 vector
```

But shouldn't they give the same output? Am I missing something really obvious?

Edit:
There's a warning when compiling that says:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:233:26: warning: the address of ‘vector3 vec1()’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]
  cout << "Vector 1: " << vec1 << endl;
```

Comment: Compile that with warnings on.

Comment: How do I do that with g++?

Comment: Add the appropriate options when compiling (e.g., `-Wall`).

Comment: @0x499602D2, As far as I know, MVP is `A a(B())`. Similar, and both have the same problem, but I think that was the main point MVP was defined from.

Comment: Show your whole code because your output is not revealing the code you provided. How can `cout << vec1` return `1` when you initialize it at `0` ?

Comment: @captainjamie, `vector3 vec1;` is enough to call the default constructor.

Comment: @chris Oh yeah, but I'd say it's a "vexing" parse in that it is often confused for a default constructor call.

Comment: @user3018144, Because a function pointer can be converted to `bool` implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector3 vec1();
```

You're declaring a function here, and displaying a function pointer. Use:

```
vector3 vec1;
```

Comment: Ok, phew thanks. That fixed it. Any idea why it can't have `()`s?

Comment: Just because that would be ambiguous with a function declaration :)

Comment: Hmm, ok, yes, I suppose it would. I hadn't considered that, since I tend to write all my functions outside of the main loop. Thanks

Comment: I tried to but it said I had to wait 8 minutes about 4 minutes ago EDIT:  
There you go :)